# Old XP software on Windows 7 Compatibility Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, compatibility, xp-mode

I have an old video player software that works happily on XP but refuses to play in Windows 7. I have tried "Compatibility Mode", which of course doesn't work (does it ever?)

The software plays proprietary CCTV video files and is the only software able to do this. I need to get it to play in Windows 7. I can play it in a Virtual Box XP or XP mode, but that is a pain for my application.

My question is: What might be preventing the software from playing? How might I go about finding the problem?

The software is a stand-along single exe. It doesn't install. Double click on the exe in XP and it opens and plays. Double click in Win7 and it opens and shows a black play window.

Alternatively, is there any 3rd party software out there that does a better version of "compatibility mode"?

Any thoughts?

Comment: did you write the software yourself? If so, tell us about it. If not, this is off topic here.

Comment: I didn't write the XP software myself but I am writing the Windows 7 (c#) software which tries to launch it. Sorry if that is off topic.

Comment: Windows 7 has lots of compatibility modes. See the compat tab on a program. Which ones did you try using? Also, did you try running as administrator? Are you using a video card that has XPDM support? What is the symptom that you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy, XP software is a hit-or-miss within Windows 7.  I've been through the headaches many times with software that I have to distribute using older software that was released initially for Win XP.

The only consistent solution that I have found has been to have my users use Windows 7 Professional or Enterprise and download and install Windows XP Mode.  Windows XP Mode is effectively a virtual machine of Windows XP running in Win7.  Using this method, I haven't had any problems.  You can find information about XP Mode, as well as downloading and installing instructions from the [Microsoft XP Mode web page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/get-started.aspx).

Comment: You are probably correct that there is no alternative to XP Mode. But the start up time and resources needed are a bit of a pain for my application.